# get value from children component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

i have children component ,i have defining the attributes in mytop level component and then passing these down to my nested components. That way, when the nested component updates the attribute value, it will be immediately reflected in the parent component.

when i want to get the values of my two attributes, i get undefined

parent component

```
 <aura:attribute name="valueList" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="valuePickList " type="String"/>

<c:PicklistMapping    valuePickList = "{!item.result.value}" valueList = "{!v.valueList}"  />
```

my children component

```
  <aura:attribute name="ValuePickList" type="String" default="" />
  <aura:attribute name="valueList" type="String"/>
```

parent.js

```
  console.log('value= ' + component.get('v.valuePickList'));
  console.log('value= ' + component.get('v.valueList'));
```

Comment: You are not binding the attribute `valuePickList` in child with the parent's values. You will need to use `valuePickList = "{!v.valuePickList}"` if you need to bind the values. Take a look at [Data Binding Between Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`component.get('v.valuePickList')` will give you the value of attribute value `valuePickList` of same component. But as you need the attribute value from child, first you need to identify the child (through `aura:id`) and then get the attribute value from it:

```
<c:PicklistMapping  aura:id="mapping"  valuePickList = "{!item.result.value}" valueList = "{!v.valueList}"  />
```

and in JS:

```
console.log('value= ' + component.find('mapping').get('v.valuePickList'));
console.log('value= ' + component.find('mapping').get('v.valueList'));
```